# Integration over the cube in $R^n$ of $\int (Tr(X \cdot X^T) )^2 dX$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $C_{a,b}$ be a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align}
C_{a,b}= \{X \in \mathbb{R}^n:   a \le X_i \le b, \forall i\in {1,...n} \} 
\end{align}
where  $X_i$ is the $i$-projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How to find the following integral
\begin{align}
\int_{C_{a,b}} (Tr(X \cdot X^T) )^2 dX
\end{align}

Here is my solution. Is it correct? Is there a better way of doing it?
Here some possible way of re-writing the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{C_{a,b}} (Tr(X \cdot X^T) )^2 dX&= \int_{C_{a,b}} ( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^2 dX \\
&=\int_{C_{a,b}} (X^T X)^2 dX \\
&=\int_{C_{a,b}} X^T X X^T X dX\\
&= \int_{C_{a,b}} \sum_j \sum_i X_i^2X_j^2 dX
\end{align}
Using the last way of writing the integral we have that

\begin{align}
\int_{C_{a,b}} \sum_j \sum_i X_i^2X_j^2 dX&= \sum_j \sum_i\int_{C_{a,b}}  X_i^2X_j^2 dX\\
&=\sum_j \sum_i\int_a^b \int_a^b  X_i^2X_j^2 dX_i dX_j\\
&= \sum_j \sum_i  \left( \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}\right)^2= n^2  \left( \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}\right)^2
\end{align}

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. What you need to compute is
$$
\int_a^b\cdots \int_a^b \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i^2x_j^2\,dx_1\cdots dx_n.
$$
Observe that
$$
\int_a^b\cdots \int_a^b  x_i^2x_j^2\,dx_1\cdots dx_n
=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
(b-a)^{n-2}\cdot\frac{(b^3-a^3)^2}{9} & \text{if} & i\ne j \\
(b-a)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{b^5-a^5}{5} & \text{if} & i= j.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you.